# How can I make a hyperlink in kivy?

Tags: python-2.7, hyperlink, kivy

How can I make a link that opens a web browser in Kivy? I've tried just putting the url in a label, but of course that doesn't work. I'd like it to work on the android app specifically and allow users to click it to open a web browser to that link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to make the text clickable with the `ref` markup tag (see the [markup documentation](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.text.markup.html) for details), and then bind it to a function that opens a web browser at the right page. On the desktop you could use the webbrowser module, on android you'll want to call android's normal functions with pyjnius. There's a prewritten example of how to do so [here](https://github.com/knappador/kivy-browser/blob/master/src/browser/androidbrowser.py).

This is something that will probably go in the [plyer](https://github.com/kivy/plyer) project, which would provide a cross-platform way to open the right web browser on any supported system with a single python interface. It's not added yet though.

Comment: webbrowser call is working also under android. You don't need to do something for that

Answer (score 9):

Use [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html), it works already on Desktop, and our toolchain for iOS / Android have implemented a backend for it. Ie, use it, it will just works everywhere:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("http://kivy.org/")
```

Answer (score 4):

Now i make It perfact code for hyper link...you just need to use insance and function here is code :

```html
#import necessary library
import webbrowser


def any_Function(instance):

  webbrowser.open('http://www.anywebsite.domain')



class TutorialApp(App):
    def build(self):

      btn1 = Button(text='Open Link' , size=(200,50), size_hint=(None, None))
      btn1.bind(on_press=any_Function)

      #Bind function with button

      return btn1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TutorialApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but it took me quite a while to work this out so I figured that maybe someone else down the road might benefit. It's far from perfect but I made a hyperlink widget.

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import webbrowser

"""A kivy widget that implements a hyperlink"""
class Hyperlink(Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      self.target = kwargs.pop('target')
      kwargs['markup'] = True
      kwargs['color'] = (0,0,1,1)
      kwargs['text'] = "[u][ref=link]{}[/ref][/u]".format(kwargs['text'])
      kwargs['on_ref_press'] = self.link
      super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def link(self, *args):
      webbrowser.open(self.target)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#import necessary library
from tkinter import Button
import webbrowser
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App 




def any_Function(instance):
    webbrowser.open('http://www.anywebsite.domain')



class TutorialApp(App):
    def build(self):

      btn1 = Button(text='Open Link' , size=(200,50), size_hint=(None, None))
      btn1.bind(on_press=any_Function)

      #Bind function with button

      return btn1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TutorialApp().run()
```

Comment: kindly import App, Button. as in the codes above it will work for you as it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
   #:kivy 2.3.0
   #:import webbrowser webbrowser
                Your stuff
                Label:
                   markup: True
                   text: 'markup me if you like'
                   on_touch_down: webbrowser.open('https//www.yourlink.com')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!